# Determining Zend Framework version without version.php file

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

The problem is that I can't find the version.php file on the server within the Zend folder. The developer left so all I got is the source code which are also encrypted. I tried to call echo Zend_Version::VERSION; but Zend said "version.php" is not there. So I am out of means.

So I need to know:

1. What is the Zend Framework number? ( 1.? or 2.?)
2. As encrypted as the source code now is from what I see on the server, is it possible for someone to keep developing it? (I know PHP but not Zend Framework.)

Appreciated.

Comment: maybe you mean obfuscated...

Comment: I don't know. Some Zend Guard Encryped or obfuscated?

Comment: if it's obfuscated, you can deobfuscate. there are a bunch of tools that do that for you

Comment: The whole project is like hundreds of php files scattered. So is this what I must do if I want to keep developing it?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can identify ZF major version by looking at directory structure even files are obfuscated.

- [ZF 1.12 Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.project.html)
- [ZF 1.12 module Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/project-structure.filesystem.html)
- [ZF 2.0 Directory Structure](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/ref/project.structure.html)

Answer (score 0):

For ZF2 < 2.5 you can go to `vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Version/Version.php`

For Zf2 >= 2.5 you can go to

```
vendor/zendframework/zend-version/src/Version.php
```

And then in this class Version.php you have a constant wich tells you what version do you have (complete form with minor)

For Zf1 I have no clue, since I'm not using it.

Answer (score 0):

For ZF1, you can check via /library/Zend/Version.php